# Error Fetching Data(flashcards in this context)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So the issue I'm having is where a owner creates a set just fine as well flashcards. BUT! once the owner send a exact same link of the url to another user(viewer) the flashcards doesnt render altho fetched. So overall my issue lies where the viewer CANNOT see the rendered flashcards

```ts
const fetchFlashcards = async (userId: any, setId: any) => {
  console.log("Fetching flashcards for set", setId, "of user", userId);

  try {
    console.log("Querying Firestore for flashcards...");

    const flashcardsRef = collection(
      db,
      "users",
      userId,
      "flashcardSets",
      setId,
      "flashcards",
    );
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(flashcardsRef, orderBy("order")));
    const fetchedFlashcards = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...(doc.data() as Flashcard),
    }));
    console.log("Fetched Flashcards:", fetchedFlashcards);
    setFlashcards(fetchedFlashcards);

    const flashcardSetRef = doc(db, "users", userId, "flashcardSets", setId);
    const flashcardSetSnapshot = await getDoc(flashcardSetRef);

    if (flashcardSetSnapshot.exists()) {
      const flashcardSetData = flashcardSetSnapshot.data() as FlashcardSet;
      console.log("Flashcard Set Data:", flashcardSetData);
      const currentUser = auth.currentUser;
      setIsOwner(flashcardSetData.ownerEmail === currentUser?.email);
      console.log(
        "Is Owner:",
        flashcardSetData.ownerEmail === currentUser?.email,
      );
    }

    console.log(`Fetching flashcards for user: ${userId}, set: ${setId}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching flashcards:", error);
  }
};
```

the console.log outputs would be this

```
Current User: UserImpl
page.tsx:108 Authenticated User Email: exampleemail.com
page.tsx:121 Current User: UserImpl
page.tsx:61 Fetching flashcards for set 1sEOlBLmP4LEcoDoKoA8 of user DJIjfoP8Q1XbEXR4yKwywt16dso2
page.tsx:64 Querying Firestore for flashcards...
page.tsx:81 Fetched Flashcards: Array(0) <---- gets 0 even tho its suppose to be 5(the amount of flashcards inside the flashcardSet the owner made)
page.tsx:334 Fetched Flashcard Sets: Array(1) <--- fetched the viewers flashcardSets(its for another portion of the code but you can ignore this as its irrelevant in this topic)
page.tsx:98 Fetching flashcards for user: DJIjfoP8Q1XbEXR4yKwywt16dso2(OWNER UID), set: 1sEOlBLmP4LEcoDoKoA8 (FLASHCARD SET OF THE OWNER UID)
```

THIS IS ALL ON THE VIEWERS/NON-OWNER PERSPECTIVE!

```
Current User: UserImpl
page.tsx:108 Authenticated User Email: owner@gmail.com
page.tsx:121 Current User: UserImpl
page.tsx:61 Fetching flashcards for set 1sEOlBLmP4LEcoDoKoA8 of user vlAgalDZy0TisZq887liWA7CmSj1
page.tsx:64 Querying Firestore for flashcards...
page.tsx:81 Fetched Flashcards: Array(5) <---- the amount of flashcards the owner made
page.tsx:334 Fetched Flashcard Sets: Array(3) <---amount of the owners flashcardSets
page.tsx:89 Flashcard Set Data: Object
page.tsx:92 Is Owner: true 
page.tsx:98 Fetching flashcards for user: vlAgalDZy0TisZq887liWA7CmSj1, set: 1sEOlBLmP4LEcoDoKoA8
```

(THIS IS THE OWNERS PERSPECTIVE!)

(note: firebase permissions isn't an issue, as i got it inspected multiple times)

Tried multiple things, alternative code, tracking down the issue, but nothing....
the output i want it is where the flashcards will render from the flashcardSet from the creator of the set, but will get none of the flashcards to render but render/works for the owner.

Comment: Why would documents in one collection have any relevance on documents in another? Your `userId` parameters make up part of the collection path and they are different in the two samples you've provided

Comment: When you step through the code to do some basic troubleshooting, what line is failing or has an unexpected result?